# Are Maximum Stats Still Boosted by Weapon Abilities?

Tags: final-fantasy-10

There are lots of `X +20%` weapon/armor abilities.

If I have a character who has 255 of stat X, is the weapon/armor bonus still applied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The final result is affected by the percentile increase, but not the (hard-capped) stat itself.

For example: the strength stat is hard capped at 255. The only way to actually raise the strength stat now is by using [Cheer](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Cheer_%28Ability%29#Final_Fantasy_X) 5 times, making it 260.

Now you equip a weapon with +20% Strength. This does not increase the strength stat by 20%. It affects physical damage directly, instead. This goes for all similar abilities.

So while the weapon/armor ability **will** increase the damage you do, even at the hard capped value of 255, it does *not* increase the stat directly.

Sources: [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/643146-final-fantasy-x-x-2-hd-remaster/68958212) and [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/197344-final-fantasy-x/44664499)

Comment: Incredible! So this makes lousy low percentage modifiers like +5% useful even if you have less than 20 in a stat! I never knew this.