# Quick Hit Versus Doublecast

Tags: final-fantasy-10

I see Quick Hit as the recommended method of dealing with basically everything late game in Final Fantasy X.

Why isn't Doublecast ever recommended for dealing with anything late game?

**EDIT:**

Doublecast is Rank 3 and Quick Hit is Rank 2 (on the remastered versions of Final Fantasy X.)

This means that you can get in 3 spells to every 2 attacks. Presumably every attack does 99,999 damage late game, so it seems like Doublecast would be better.

Comment: Are you saying to use Double cast and cast 2 Quick Hits? Normally a mage would have Double cast and would not have Quick Hit

Comment: @Huangism I've edited to clarify.

Comment: I've always wondered this myself ever since the international and later editions made Quick Hit slightly less ridiculous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The damage done to Penance by a Maximum Magic character under the effect of Focus x 5 is 39,000: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/643146-final-fantasy-x-x-2-hd-remaster/69088560#5

According to the answer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/215821/53654) Magic +20% is applied directly to the damage dealt by an attack based in that stat, so: the damage dealt to Penance would be 46,800.

Since Doublecast will do Ultima twice you're looking at a total damage of 93,600.

With Maximum Strength *and* 170 Luck you can do 99,999 critical damage per hit against Penance on a Quick Hit.

Since the Rank of Doublecast is 3 and the Rank of Quick Hit is 2 This means you'll get 2 attacks to every 3 casts, so your actual attack damage would be: 199,998 and your actual cast damage would be: 140,400.

**If we use Penance as the gold standard of Doublecast versus Quick Hit, Doublecast is about 70% as effective as Quick Hit.**

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the damage being lower against endgame bosses due to not ignoring defense, double Ultima has other downsides.

The weapon required needs Break Damage Limit and Magic Booster. Only one celestial weapon has Magic Booster- the Onion Knight. This is widely considered among the most difficult to get and Lulu is objectively the worst endgame character due to weak overdrive. Acquiring a BDL weapon requires either 80 Dark Matter or a lucky drop from a Dark Aeon.

Ultima also has a ridiculously long cast time, especially when Doublecast. A fair amount of endgame content involves grinding where the damage per turn is less important than the damage over time. Replacing it with Flare is more reasonable but still takes 4-5 times as long as a non-Lulu Attack.

Ultima does hit multiple targets but this is less useful than one would expect. Only 3 post game battles have multiple targets- Penance, Magus Sisters, and Ultima Buster.