# Piercing or Critical For Magic Attacks?

Tags: final-fantasy-10

Is there a way to boost my magic damage?

Celestial Weapons ignore physical but not magical defense, or custom weapons can have the Piercing ability applied to them.

Physical attacks can also get critical damage.

Is there a "Piercing ability" or critical hit for magic attacks?

Comment: Does piercing actually apply to magic attacks? I always thought it was a melee thing.

Comment: @Huangism I guess I didn't ask the question well. Yes Piercing is only for physical attacks. I wanted to know if there was a magical equivalent to Piercing.

Comment: Oh I think it would help your cause if you edited the title to something like that, more straight forward. I think Auron's Magic break is what you are looking for. I cannot remember if that attribute is on a weapon or not

Comment: @Huangism I've edited. You're thinking of Mental Break and that won't work cause everything late game is immune to it. I need abilities that modify my attack, cause I cant really modify the targets defense.

Comment: Yes different name on the int version. I don't think such thing exist. I believe in late game bosses, melee is the way to go. Although Holy does a lot of dmg specially if you get doublecast and 1mp thing going

Comment: @Huangism Sadly you can only Doublecast Black Magic, so Doublecast Ultima is usually your best bet: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/218700/53654

Comment: Oh right, it must of been something I used Yuna with then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking over [this list of weapon and armor abilities](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Final_Fantasy_X_Auto-Abilities), I can conclusively say: **No, there is no ability which ignores magic defense.**

Conversely there is no physical corollary for Magic Booster which: "Increases potency of magic spells by 50% but doubles their MP cost."

As far as criticals, **magic cannot critical**: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/643146-final-fantasy-x-x-2-hd-remaster/68388299 I wish I had a better source but I can empirically say that I have never seen a magic critical.

(Note that I'm referring to castable magic not thigs like Kimahri's overdrives which can critical.)